# Audio works fine on Windows 10 but not on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound

Here is the HW report:
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=faf3c3a1ae
Thanks for help

Comment: I barely see anything here. Please include more details.

Comment: Please post any info that will help with the question into the body of the question. What does not work on Ubuntu mean?

Comment: @RishonJR, 
 if you scroll down the HW report a little it says on the second line High Definition Audio it detected, but not working. Result is no sound.

Comment: Detected != Works

Comment: @matigo I know, how can I make it work?

Comment: @Kemal try running `pavucontrol` and switch to the tab `Output devices`. You should see there a drop-down list, what does it have? Also, does audio start working if you plug or unplug headphones?

Comment: @Hi-Angel list says its unplugged, but it was, so I unplugged and pluged again to no avail. Should I reboot?

Comment: @Kemal no, don't reboot. I mean: what elements does the drop-down list have? Is it the `Headphones (unplugged)` and `Speakers`? Also, does the sound work in headphones?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Bingo! it works now, the headphones, many many thanks

Comment: No problem, but wait, that looks like just a workaround. Do you still have the problem without headphones plugged-in? That is, do you have the problem with your built-in speakers? If you do, can you check that the volume isn't muted, try also to max it out.

Comment: @Hi-Angel this is Pico PC, it does not have built-in speakers only head phones.

Comment: Still, it's pretty unclear, plus it makes it hard to read for the others. Try to keep things minimal and inside the question post.

Comment: @RishonJR OK, I understand, regards